# LEADTOOLS Barcode Generation iOS

Tags: ios, barcode, leadtools-sdk, gs1-databar

I want to generate a barcode image for a "GS1 Databar Expanded Stack" code using LEADTOOLS iOS SDK, but I can't find a proper way to do this (or any other type of code). Their examples contains only a "reading" demo, not a "writing" one. 
Can anyone suggest a way to generate barcodes in iOS using LEADTOOLS SDK?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The LEADTOOLS iOS/OSX toolkit does support writing barcodes, including GS1 DataBar Expanded. The iOS demo shipped with the toolkit does not implement this functionality because iOS devices are used more frequently for reading rather than writing barcodes. However, the barcode writing functionality is implemented in the OSX barcode demo shipped with the same toolkit, and it should be fairly easy to take that code from the OSX demo and use it within an iOS project almost without change.
If you try to use the writing functions in an iOS project and face problems, post the details of the problem here or send them to LEADTOOLS support.

Comment: I have already tried integrating the OSX "barcode generation" code in iOS and I'm getting "LeadTools error 0" which I have no idea what it means. Could you help me with that?